# Typewriter effect with tailwindcss

Tags: reactjs, tailwind-css

I am stuck at some typewriter effect wanted to include in my ReactComponebt.

For the typewriting effect itself I am wrote following component:

```
import React from "react"

interface TypewriterProps {
  text: string
  minTypeSpeed: number
  maxTypeSpeed: number
  initDelay: number
  className?: string
}

interface TypewriterState {
  text: string
}

class Typewriter extends React.Component<TypewriterProps, TypewriterState> {
  static defaultProps = {
    text: "Hello world!",
    minTypeSpeed: 50,
    maxTypeSpeed: 90,
    initDelay: 700,
    className: "",
  }

  constructor(props: TypewriterProps) {
    super(props)
    this.state = {
      text: "",
    }
  }

  clicketyClack() {
    let str = ""
    let typeSpeed = 0

    this.props.text.split("").forEach((c: string, index: number) => {
      typeSpeed +=
        Math.random() * (this.props.maxTypeSpeed - this.props.minTypeSpeed) +
        this.props.minTypeSpeed
      setTimeout(() => {
        str += c
        this.setState({ text: str })
      }, this.props.initDelay + typeSpeed)
    })
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    this.clicketyClack()
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div className={this.props.className}>
        {this.state.text}
        <span className="bg-teal-600 bg-opacity-60 animate-caret">&nbsp;</span>
      </div>
    )
  }
}

export default Typewriter
```

That works just fine. But one samll part not. The line `<span className="bg-teal-600 bg-opacity-60 animate-caret">&nbsp;</span>` contains the `animate-caret`, whcih is a custom made animation in the `tailwind.config.js:

```
[...]
  theme: {
    extend: {
      animation: {
        caret: 'caret 1s steps(1) infinite',
      },
    },
    fontFamily: {
      [...]
    },
  },
  plugins: [],
}
```

Also added

```
@keyframes caret {
    to { background-position: 100%; }
  }
```

to the `global.css`

For my understanding I should now have a blinking caret at the line end. But that is not the case.
May someone can see my mistake and help me out.

Answer (score 0):

Ok I got the solution. Fucket up the css in the `global.css`.

```
@keyframes caret {
    50% {
      background-color: transparent;
    }
}
```

works fine :)